# Проверка данных на пустоту

Tags: node.js, express

Делаю добавление продавца в базу данных. Столкнулся с тем, как проверить переданные данные на сервер на пустоту. Сперва я проверяю `email`, передавая его в `Merchant.getCheckMerchantSQL(req.body.merchant_email)`, на то нет ли такого в базе данных. Затем мне надо проваерить весь `let merchant` на то, что все поля заполнены, так как в базе данных стоит у все полей `NOT NULL`. Как проверить каждые `req.body...`?

Делаю так, но он проверяет не значения полей, а сами поля. Как сделать чтобы он проверял значения полей?

```
if(req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
  console.log('Object missing');
}
```

Сама функция добавления

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    db.query(Merchant.getCheckMerchantSQL(req.body.merchant_email), (err, data) => {
        if (data.rows.length !== 0) {
            res.status(401).json({
                failed: 'A merchant with this email address already exists'
            });
        } else {
            let merchant = new Merchant(
                req.body.merchant_name,
                req.body.busines_number,
                req.body.busines_owner,
                req.body.busines_hours,
                req.body.merchant_email,
                req.body.contact_number,
                req.body.category,
                req.body.merchant_address,
                req.body.merchant_address_optional,
                req.body.type_location,
                req.body.city,
                req.body.province,
                req.body.country,
                req.body.store_photos,
                req.body.subscription_type
            );
            let merchant_parole = generator.generate({
                length: 10,
                numbers: true
            });
            let mailOptions = {
                from: '',
                to: req.body.merchant_email,
                subject: "Your login password",
                html: "Hello, <br> Your profile password: " + merchant_parole
            }
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
            bcrypt.hash(merchant_parole, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
                db.query(merchant.getAddMerchantSQL(hash), (err, data) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.status(200).json({
                            message: 'Merchant register'
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error: err
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: разве цикл  для этого не подходит?

Comment: я думал об этом, но посчитал что есть более правильное решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы вообще рекомендовал для валидации полей использовать [express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator)
.

Немного роут изменится, будет что-то типо:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
router.post('/add', [
        check('merchant_name').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        check('busines_number').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        // и так для остальных полей
    ]
    (req, res) => {
        try {
            // ошибка валидации
            validationResult(req).throw();

            // остальной код
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(422).json(...);
        }
});
```